# Is this demonstration of uniform convergence sufficient?

Tags: uniform-convergence

Let's have $f_n(x)$ defined on $\mathbb{R}$ by:

- $f_n(0)=0$
- $f_n(x)=\frac{1-e^{-nx^2x^2}}{x}$if $x\neq 0$

$f_n(x)\rightarrow \frac{1}{x}$

therefore, $f_n(x)$ converges weakly to $\frac{1}{x}$
\begin{align}
\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow +\infty}\sup\limits_{n\in I}{|f_n(x)-f(x)|}&=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow +\infty}\sup\limits_{n\in I}{|\frac{1-e^{-n^2x^2}}{x}-\frac{1}{x}|}\\
&=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow +\infty}|\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x}|\\
&=0
\end{align}

Hence $f_n(x)$ uniformly-converges.

I'm not sure about my demostration of uniform convergence when I change $|f_n(x)-f(x)|$. Can you tell me if I can improve it?

Answer (score 2):

For the sequence $f_n(x)$ to be uniformly convergent for $x\in \mathbb{R}$, one requires that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\left|f_n(x)-f(x)\right|=0 \tag 1$$

However, we have

$$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1-e^{-n^2x^2}}{x}&,x\ne 0\\\\
0&,x=0
\end{cases}$$

and therefore

$$\begin{align}
f(x)&=\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(x)\\\\
&=\begin{cases}
\frac1x&,x\ne 0\\\\
0&,x=0
\end{cases}
\end{align}$$

Since the limit function is discontinuous at $x=0$, then $f_n(x)$ is not uniformly continuous on any interval that either contains $0$ or has $0$ as a limit point.

To see that $(1)$ is violated, we simply note that for $x=1/n$ we have

$$\begin{align}
\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\left(\left|\frac{1-e^{-n^2x^2}}{x}-\frac1x\right|\right)&=\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\left(\frac{e^{-n^2x^2}}{|x|}\right)\\\\
&\ge n/e\to \infty
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

The reason why your argument doesn't work is that you assumed that 
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{x \in \mathbb R} \left| f_n(x) - f(x) \right| =\sup_{x \in \mathbb R}  \lim_{n \to \infty} \left| f_n(x) - f(x) \right|,
$$
which is essentially asking that pointwise convergence and uniform convergence are equivalent (because you computed the limit inside pointwise), and this is definitely *not* the case. (By the way, you swapped the roles of $x$ and $n$ in your computations.) You should always be careful when you try to pull in limits inside things like supremum or series ; in general, you should worry about commuting any two operations (limits, series, supremums/infimums, etc.) applied on some entity.

The key to determining uniform convergence is to bound the quantity
$$
\left| f_n(x) - f(x) \right|
$$
by something independent of $x$ (in other words, find an upper bound for the supremum, it can be a function of $n$ in this case since $\sup_{x \in \mathbb R} |f_n(x) - f(x)|$ does depend on $n$ after all) and then make sure this bound goes to zero as $n$ goes to infinity.

Hope that helps,

Comment: The OP actually didn't just swap the limit with the supremum, the $x$ and the $n$ were reversed also.  Note the supremum in the OP is on $ns while the limit was on $x$.  But I think your answer could be useful any way.  So, +1

Comment: @Dr.MV : I copy-pasted to include my first math line, so I didn't notice at first, but then I added a remark between parentheses. I kind of mechanically answered without reading much... Thanks! Your answer was great too. I didn't add a solution since it's pretty hard to do better than yours, but I thought the comment was relevant.